# Help with a 3d wall

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, modifiers

Wanna modelling wall panels, i have 2 samples[image][image] but i dont have any skills, mb can someone share the technique of execution, i try use displacement with dragons skin on second picture, but I did not like the result.